# How to change parallax image position from its default top

Tags: parallax.js

Actually i am using parallax.js for scrolling effect. but that parallax image was hidden into the top portion of the header there by i can see only the bottom side. i want to view the parallaxed image top portion or the full image.

i used data attribute

```
<div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" class="parallax-container" data-parallax="scroll" data-position="top" data-bleed="10" data-image-src="images/prodct-bnr1.jpg" data-natural-width="1360" data-natural-height="435" >
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you adjust the height of your div, for example I used 600px and also you don't need data-bleed it will move your div 10px up.